# Adding a running number with string index to a dataframe in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

New to Spark. Is it possible  to add an index column to an existing dataset which is combination of string and running number

Right now am creating a dynamic index with monotonically_increasing_id function

```
List<Employee> columns = Arrays.asList(new Employee("john" ,"Lead"), new Employee("Doe" ,"Master"));
dataset = dataset.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id());
dataset = dataset.select(col("index"),col("name"),col("desc"));

 index|name|  desc|
+-----+----+------+
|    0|john|  Lead|
|    1| Doe|Master|
```

Would like to have the index column with string and index number. something like below

```
 index|name|  desc|
+-----+----+------+
|   E0|john|  Lead|
|   E1| Doe|Master|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` to add a `E` at the beginning:

```
dataset = dataset.select(concat(lit("E"), col("index")).alias("index"),col("name"),col("desc"));
```